# Inline style not working on images - Jekyll - Zurb Ink - HTML Email Design

Tags: html, css, inline, zurb-ink

I've got these two social icons in the footer of this email and I want them to sit side by side (inline). It says they're inline in the inspector, I thought maybe the td area was to narrow so I widened it.. that's not it.. can't seem to figure it out. Tried `inline-block` too .. Any ideas?

http://onlyaction.github.io/snfm/2015/09/21/SNFM-0313.html

--

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please remove `clear: both;` in:

```
img {
    outline: 0px none;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    float: left;
    clear: both;      /* This is causing it */
    display: block;
}
```

Use below CSS to target the icons so that it does not effect other images.

```
img.social {
  clear: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Manoj Kumar ;)

Comment: Removing float:left also seems to fix it.

Comment: @Steve Yeah, it's another solution. But then `clear: both;` is not needed neither :)

Comment: Thanks ! That fixed it.